# Adding different number types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm have been using Haskell for a while and I'm having some trouble with Numeric Types. Most of the time I can solve the after trying around a bit but this time i have been stumped for over two hours by this trivial piece of code.

I have these Functions:

```
takeLessEqual x = takeWhile (<=x)

leftHalf x = takeLessEqual x $ (map (\x -> ((x+0.5)*(x+0.5) + 0.75))) [1..]
-- Produces the list [3.0,7.0,13.0,21.0,31.0,43.0 ... (some number < x)]

rightHalf x = takeLessEqual x $ (map (\x -> if even x then x*x + 1 else x*x)) [1..]
-- Produces the list [1,5,9,17,25,37,49 ... (some number < x)]   

total x = (sum $ rightHalf x) + (sum $ leftHalf x)
-- total 10 Should produce some number 25 or 25.0
```

It loads without error in to ghci, but when i try to evaluate:

```
*> leftHalf 10 
[3.0,7.0]
it :: (Ord a, Fractional a, Enum a) => [a]

*> rightHalf 10
[1,5,9]
it :: Integral a => [a]

*> total 10

<interactive>:150:1: error:
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘it’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Fractional a0)’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Fractional Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    instance Fractional Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
• In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
  In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

And I have tried adding type annotations at various points and converting types with toInteger and fromIntegral with no success.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try: `total 10 :: Double`

Comment: I already tried this ofc --> 
    • No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of ‘total’
    • In the expression: total 10 :: Double
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = total 10 :: Double

Comment: Yes, the problem is that Haskell does not have any type that is both `Integral` and `Fractional` at the same time, but your `total` functions needs such a type!

Comment: fwiw, you can rewrite `leftHalf` as `leftHalf x = takeLessEqual x $ map (\x -> (x * x + x + 1) [1..]` and it'll work for all numeric types, not just `Integral` or `Fractional` types.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, I would like to recommend that you definitely follow GHC's suggestion of adding type signatures. I recommend always giving type signatures to top-level definitions. This will make the error messages *significantly* more clear.

If we go ahead and do that, assuming that the `Fractional` type you want is `Double` and the `Integral` type is `Int`, we have

```
takeLessEqual :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
takeLessEqual x = takeWhile (<=x)

leftHalf :: Double -> [Double] -- This must be some `Fractional` type since we are doing things like adding by 0.5
leftHalf x = takeLessEqual x $ (map (\x -> ((x+0.5)*(x+0.5) + 0.75))) [1..]

rightHalf :: Int -> [Int]      -- This must be some `Integral` type since we are using `even`
rightHalf x = takeLessEqual x $ (map (\x -> if even x then x*x + 1 else x*x)) [1..]

-- total :: ?
total x = (sum $ rightHalf x) + (sum $ leftHalf x)
```

Note that there is no type that is both `Integral` and `Fractional`, so we cannot use the same number type everywhere here.

The problem now is that the two sides of `+` in `total` are not the same type, even though they must be (`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`).

Now, you need to decide if you want to end up using `Double`s or `Int`s (or a combination. I will assume you want `Double` for both the input and the output):

```
total :: Double -> Double
```

Now, we see that `rightHalf` needs an `Int`, so we must use either `ceiling`, `floor` or `round` to convert the argument from a `Double`. The result we get back is a `[Int]` fed into `sum`, which gives us an `Int` (since `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`).

Assuming `ceiling` gives the rounding we want, we end up with:

```
total x = (fromIntegral . sum . rightHalf $ ceiling x) + (sum $ leftHalf x)
```

On a stylistic note, I would also suggest writing `... + sum (leftHalf x)` instead of `... + (sum $ leftHalf x)`.

In general, if you want to go from a fractional type to an integral type, you will want to use `floor`, `ceiling` or `round`. If you want to go from an integral type to anything else (usually a fractional type, but possible some different integral type), you will want `fromIntegral`.

You could do the conversions in a different spot (in `leftHalf` and/or `rightHalf`). It seems like those two functions should stay floating and integral respectively though, since you would have to choose a rounding method (when the function that calls those two should probably be able to decide on a rounding method).